# Detecting Firefox extension uninstall event

Tags: firefox-addon

I have a bootstrapped extension and in `bootstrap.js` there is an uninstall event:

```js
function uninstall(data, reason) {
     console.log('uninstall event');
}
```

But when I uninstall my extension `uninstall` function isn't writing 'uninstall event' on console.

I've set `extensions.logging.enabled` to `true` using `about:config`. On uninstall this prints on console:

> LOG addons.xpi: Calling bootstrap method uninstall on user@example.com version 1.4

But my custom message written in `uninstall` event doesn't print.

Comment: Try using dump('uninstall event') and see if it returns what your expecting.

Comment: Maybe this will help: `exports.onUnload = function (reason) {};`?